# User cannot create btrfs snapshot of subvolume in Debian 10 the way it is done in Centos 6

Tags: linux, btrfs, snapshot

I migrated a CentOS 6 install to Debian 10 and btrfs snapshotting is heavily used on these system.
Under CentOS I can easily have two users - user1 and user2, which are part of group - user1user2group. When I do a snapshot with one of the users and have g+rw on this snapshot the other used should be able to snapshot this subvolume as well:

```
user1@somehost:/BTRFS$ mkdir folder 
user1@somehost:/BTRFS$ chown user1:user1user2group folder/             
user1@somehost:/BTRFS$ chmod 770 folder/ 
user1@somehost:/BTRFS$ cd folder/ 
user1@somehost:/BTRFS/folder$ btrfs subvolume create snap-shot 
    Create subvolume './snap-shot' 
user1@somehost:/BTRFS/folder$ chown user1:user1user2group snap-shot/ 
user1@somehost:/BTRFS/folder$ chmod 770 snap-shot/ 
user1@somehost:/BTRFS/folder$ su - user2 
user2@somehost:~$ cd /BTRFS/folder 
user2@somehost:/BTRFS/folder$ ls -lah 

   total 0 
   drwxrwx--- 1 user1 user1user2group  18 Jul  5 08:02 . 
   drwxrwx--- 1 user1 user1user2group  12 Jul  5 08:02 .. 
   drwxrwx--- 1 user1 user1user2group  0 Jul  5 08:03 snap-shot
```

I validate user2 has the correct rights over "snap-shot" and "folder" with simple copy:

```
user2@somehost:/BTRFS/folder$ cp -pr snap-shot copy-snap-shot
```

Then I try to create the snapshot as user2 on Debian 10:

```
user2@somehost:/BTRFS/folder$ btrfs subvolume snapshot snap-shot/ 
user2-snapshot Create a snapshot of 'snap-shot/' in './user2-snapshot' ERROR: cannot 
snapshot 'snap-shot/': Operation not permitted
```

On CentOS the last command returns success:

```
Create a snapshot of 'snap-shot/' in 'user2-snapshot'
```

I know a lot of things changed in BTRFS for the last many years, but I find this rather basic functionality. Does anyone have an idea if this can be worked around?

Comment: Probably already didn't work in CentOS 7: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/log/?h=linux-3.10.y&qt=grep&q=btrfs%3A+restrict+snapshotting+to+own+subvolumes . Wasn't applied to 2.6.32 . It's up to you to search if it was applied in RHEL6/CentOS6's patched version (and thus wouldn't be the culprit).

Comment: @A.B Thank you for the reply. I guess this is exactly what we are talking about. I guess I will have to invent some workaround with sudo btrfs for the moment.
Your answer should be the correct one. I don't see any button to do that. Probably something with my account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@A.B Found the [patch](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=linux-3.10.y&id=d024206133ce21936b3d5780359afc00247655b7), which introduces this change, so I would consider this answered.